# DateTime conversion and alarm creation in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I'm trying to set an alarm in windows phone using the following code

```
    private void btnSetAlarm_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        date = (DateTime)datePicker.Value;
        time = (DateTime)timePicker.Value;
        beginTime = date + time.TimeOfDay;

        statusTextBlock.Text = beginTime.ToString(); //Display alarm time

        Alarm alarm = new Alarm("Wakeup4");
        alarm.Sound = new Uri("/Ringtones/ring.wav", UriKind.Relative);
        alarm.BeginTime = beginTime;

        ScheduledActionService.Add(alarm);
        MessageBox.Show("Alarm Created");
    }
```

Main problem is that when i set date as 2/17/2012 and time as 12:55 PM in the date and time picker respectively, alarm will get created but in the status bar it displays alarm set time as 2/18/2012 1:45:48 AM. Why is this happening? Is this because of time zone or what? By the way my system time is Indian standard time IST +5:30 and in the phone it is US time. I also changed phone time format to IST but it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't remember how the DatePicker works, but just to be sure you should use the 'Date' property to remove the time part of the DateTime result: `beginTime = date.Date + time.TimeOfDay`

Comment: My cristal ball tells me you ran this at 12:50:48 2/17/2012. 5 minutes or so before you wanted the alarm to go off. @KoolKiz you should give your comment as an Answer so we can all vote for it and Chandu can accept it.

Comment: @KooKiz : YOu're correct.. Please add it as an answer..

Comment: @MartinBrown : You guessed it right :) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't remember how the DatePicker works, but just to be sure you should use the 'Date' property to remove the time part of the DateTime result: beginTime = date.Date + time.TimeOfDay

Answer (score 0):

MSDN says that the time value should be in the device’s local time. Make sure that you don't have UTC somewhere (check DateTime.Kind property).